# Use vs debugger in an efficient way

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using visual studio and I have 3 different solutions.

In my main solution A, I use code from solution B and C.

I use code from B and C as I have references to B.DLL and C.DLL which are stored in c:\Bin and updated after each build of solution B and C.

I know that at some point my code will hit given method from B.DLL and from C.DLL but I don't know what path leads to it. I would just like to (somehow) put breakpoints in in both B and C on that method and wait for it to be hit.

What would be the best way to do that to have it in one run? I know that I can start A process with debbuging from solution B and that I can attach to running app but then it will be done always from one solution in which I can put breakpoint but i want to have 2 at the same time.

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: You can have the same project included in more than one solution. That way, solution B can use project B (which generates B.dll), solution C and use project C (and C.dll), but solution A can include both project B and C and can make project reference to both the B.dll and C.dll assemblies

Comment: @MickyD thanks I have it but now I know how code looks like because I have it in my solution and I know where to set break point but i dont know how to set that breakpoint from within solution A that runs a program :) should I somehow open that cs file in visual studio while having Solution A open?

Comment: @Witos  ,If you want to set a breakpoint, you it should be in the same solution explorer. So if you have use `F11` to enter the function of B and C.